# Belkin Wemo API?

Tags: wemo

Looking for some API docs on querying & control of Belkin Wemo switches/plugs.

I have discovery working but can't seem to find any concise documentations describing how to do much else.

I can see discovery events & process the xml details:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=86400
DATE: Sat, 21 Sep 2019 05:11:35 GMT
EXT:
LOCATION: http://[IP]:49153/setup.xml
OPT: "http://schemas.upnp.org/upnp/1/0/"; ns=01
01-NLS: [ID]
SERVER: Unspecified, UPnP/1.0, Unspecified
X-User-Agent: redsonic
ST: urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1
USN: uuid:Lightswitch-1_0-[ID]::urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1
```

What do I do with these? :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serviceList>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:WiFiSetup:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:WiFiSetup1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/WiFiSetup1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/WiFiSetup1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/setupservice.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:timesync:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:timesync1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/timesync1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/timesync1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/timesyncservice.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:basicevent1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/basicevent1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/basicevent1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/eventservice.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:firmwareupdate:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:firmwareupdate1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/firmwareupdate1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/firmwareupdate1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/firmwareupdate.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:rules:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:rules1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/rules1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/rules1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/rulesservice.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:metainfo:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:metainfo1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/metainfo1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/metainfo1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/metainfoservice.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:remoteaccess:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:remoteaccess1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/remoteaccess1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/remoteaccess1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/remoteaccess.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:deviceinfo:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:deviceinfo1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/deviceinfo1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/deviceinfo1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/deviceinfoservice.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:smartsetup:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:smartsetup1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/smartsetup1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/smartsetup1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/smartsetup.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
    <service>
        <serviceType>urn:Belkin:service:manufacture:1</serviceType>
        <serviceId>urn:Belkin:serviceId:manufacture1</serviceId>
        <controlURL>/upnp/control/manufacture1</controlURL>
        <eventSubURL>/upnp/event/manufacture1</eventSubURL>
        <SCPDURL>/manufacture.xml</SCPDURL>
    </service>
</serviceList>
```

Comment: The light switch is a bad example as it has no controllable endpoints (and only available in the US so I never got to play with one), but if to you download the xml file in each service entry it describes what you need to send to the  control/event urls

Comment: It has one controllable endpoint (BinaryState)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a collection of blog posts talking about reverse engineering the WeMo protocol here: https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/tag/wemo/

My work was initially with the WeMo lighting products but I also get sockets working as well. There is NodeJS [module](https://github.com/hardillb/wemo-ng) I wrote to use as the code of my Node-RED [node](https://github.com/hardillb/node-red-contrib-wemo-ng) that even covers subscribing to event notifications from the smarter power monitoring socket.

WeMo devices all use SOAP for control and are self describing because they serve up the entrypoint into the schema in the discovery response. From this you can walk all the endpoints and get a description of what the inputs to those endpoints need to be.

Comment: Any chance you could aggregate some of the endpoints/general command structure here for reference? I've scrolled through dozens of pages and haven't seen too much of that. Ideally in standard HTTP format (like what wireshark would see)

Comment: The endpoints are all listed in the Location field returned by the discovery iirc

Comment: Didn't notice that - thanks. Going to poke around in there...

Comment: Have you come across any information regarding subscribing to state change events?

Comment: Yes you have: https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2015/01/14/wemo-event-notifications/

Comment: I am observing a random port change phenomenon that goes undetected by my controller. Is there some subscribe event I should be listening to that informs when the device(s) listening port is changing?

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @hardillb for pointing me in the right direction. Here's a basic message structure for control:

```
POST /upnp/control/basicevent1
SOAPACTION: "urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1#SetBinaryState"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: [DEVICE_IP]:49153
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 306
Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:SetBinaryState xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1">
        <BinaryState>0</BinaryState>
        </u:SetBinaryState>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200
status: 200
CONTENT-LENGTH: 289
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
DATE: Tue, 24 Sep 2019 13:47:09 GMT
EXT:
SERVER: Unspecified, UPnP/1.0, Unspecified
X-User-Agent: redsonic

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:SetBinaryStateResponse xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1">
            <BinaryState>0</BinaryState>
            <CountdownEndTime>0</CountdownEndTime>
            <deviceCurrentTime>1569333003</deviceCurrentTime>
        </u:SetBinaryStateResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```